# Cancel separate and all axios requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**Problem:** I have React app that fires axios requests and you can cancel them one by one, clicking on buttons. Now I created one more button that should cancel all requests at once, but I don't know how to do it, because I already have `cancelToken` config in requests for separate cancelling.

**Question:** how to cancel all three requests from my code example by clicking on a button?

**Code example:**

Component Wrapper.jsx:

```
    const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;

    <RequestComponent cancelToken={CancelToken}>
    <RequestComponent cancelToken={CancelToken}>
    <RequestComponent cancelToken={CancelToken}>

    <button onClick={/* Something here */}>Cancel all requests</button>
```

Component RequestComponent.jsx:

```
    let cancel;

    // new axios request
    axios.get('/user/12345', {
      cancelToken: new this.props.CancelToken(function executor(c) {
        cancel = c;
      })
    });

    // cancel this one particular request
    <button onClick={cancel('Request canceled')}>Cancel this one request</button>
```

I read [axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation), but still can't figure this out.

Comment: You need to move the requests up in the component hierarchy so you have access to them from outside their `RequestComponent`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the parent component which hold the `RequestComponents`, pass an additional prop which will be called after a request.

```
<RequestComponent cancelToken={CancelToken} onRequest={persistCancel}>
<RequestComponent cancelToken={CancelToken} onRequest={persistCancel}>
<RequestComponent cancelToken={CancelToken} onRequest={persistCancel}>
```

When a request is made, persist the cancel function.

```
axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: new this.props.CancelToken(function executor(c) {
    cancel = c;
    this.props.onRequest(c);
  })
});
```

In the parent component, store the cancel function

```
persistCancel = (cancel) => {
    this.setState({cancels: [...this.state.cancels, cancel]}
}
```

Call these functions when you want to cancel all of them.

```
<button onClick={()=>{this.state.cancels.forEach((c) => c())}}>Cancel all requests</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works. Btw, there is a typo - I think you meant to name your function `persistCancel`, not `persistToken`.